# target selected members of an array

Tags: javascript

I have a series of divs of the same class; some with title attributes set - some without:

```
<div class="component_wrapper cw1" title="thisTitle1">... </div>
<div class="component_wrapper cw2" title="thisTitle2">... </div>
<div class="component_wrapper cw3" title="thisTitle3">... </div>
<div class="component_wrapper cw4" title="">... </div>
<div class="component_wrapper cw5" title="">... </div>
```

I've constructed a javascript function that loops through these divs and displays the ones with the title attribute set by setting their css display attribute to "inline":

```
function checkComponent(e){
    var hdrSet = document.getElementsByClassName("component_wrapper");
    var titles = {};

    for (var i=0; i<hdrSet.length; i++){
        if ( !titles[ hdrSet[i].title ] )  {
            titles[ hdrSet[i].title ] = true;
            hdrSet[i].style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
}
checkComponent();
```

the problem is, when I load the page the divs that I'm trying to target display (good), but also 1 of the divs not targeted displays. In the example above, the first four divs display, when all I want is the first three. What's wrong with my code... and is there an better way to construct the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks for duplicate titles, not missing ones. Here's how you could fix that:

```
function checkComponent(){
    var hdrSet = document.getElementsByClassName("component_wrapper");

    for (var i = 0; i < hdrSet.length; i++){
        if(hdrSet[i].title) {
            hdrSet[i].style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
}
checkComponent();
```

Also, if you're open to using jQuery, it's much neater and more compatible:

```
function checkComponent() {
    $('.component_wrapper[title]:not([title=""])').css('display', 'inline');
}
checkComponent();
```

Comment: I plugged in both replacement functions. It looks like the Jquery function just looks for a title attribute (as opposed to checking whether it is set or not). The other function works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @kjarsenal: You're welcome :) I also fixed the jQuery function, sorry about that.